How to set path while creating issue in Jira using python?
I want to create an issue in Jira using python, I am using the jira module for doing the same ;
I have found this code from their official documentation but I am not sure in which repository path this issue would be created in and would this return me with the 'CETM' id of the created issue ?
from jira import JIRA
issue_dict = {
    'project': {'id': 123},
    'summary': 'Title',
    'description': 'Random descp here',
    'issuetype': 'Test'
}
new_issue = jira.create_issue(fields=issue_dict)

Also, is it possible to clone an issue and return the 'CETM' id of the cloned issue, I was not able to find anything regarding it.
The code I tried is mentioned above.
